# Magento 2 cms_page_view_selectable not visible in AdminHtml CMS page Custom Layout List

Tags: magento2, custom-layout-update

I'm trying to create a Custom Layout update for a CMS page (as per https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/design/layout-update-place-block.html). On local environment it is present in the CMS Page configuration Custom Layout list but on a testing environment it is not.

Just to confirm that what I'm doing is ok, I have created the layout as below:

```
src/app/design/frontend/Vendor/default/Vendor_Theme/layout/cms_page_view_selectable_cmspage-url_LayoutCustomName.xml
```

Did some debugging on the environment and it seems that my layout update file is not being picked up by the Layout mechanism.

Local env is on developer deploy mode while testing is on production deploy mode.

I know that the issue may be related to the difference between ENVs setup, but maybe someone else bumped into the same issue and I'm missing something.

At this point I'm clueless on what the issue might be. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you resolve this, I have the same issue on 2.3.4?

Comment: My logic was in a new module. I forgot to commit the config.php file and because of that the module was not activated on the remote env thus my layout configuration was disregarded.